# Android/Java: "error: cannot find symbol import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.SupportMapFragment;"

Tags: java, android, supportmapfragment, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I just install the new version of HereMap, and impossible to run my app that worked perfectly before. The message is:

```
error: cannot find symbol import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.SupportMapFragment;
  symbol:   class SupportMapFragment
  location: package com.here.android.mpa.mapping
```

It doesn't recognize the `SupportMapFragment`

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try rebuild project and then invalidate cashes and restart?

Comment: @AlexRmcf Yep :) I already did it

Comment: That what i found in official documentation:
As of SDK 3.13. Use AndroidXMapFragment that extends Fragment from the androidx library.

@Deprecated
public class SupportMapFragment
extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: @AlexRmcf Ok I am going to test the AndroidXMapFragment '^^. I will tell if it is ok thanks